# Is there any way to add an icon image to a button in QT6?

Tags: image, button, qml, icons, qt6

I am interested in incorporating icon images into buttons, but I prefer not to rely on external files for this purpose. I am wondering if there are any pre-installed icons available in QT6 that I could use. As an example, I have included an image below that illustrates the type of icons I would like to use.

I have attempted to use the [Breeze Icons](https://marketplace.qt.io/products/breeze-icons) package,but I have been unable to determine how to implement.

[image]

Comment: You can use [freedesktop.org icons](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html) (see [icon.name](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html#icon.name-prop) property for more info) or you can create your own theme(see more info [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-icons.html#icon-themes)). [This article](https://www.pythonguis.com/faq/are-there-any-built-in-qicons/) can be useful too

Comment: I can think of a number of ways for including icons in your app without including a source file, but, the question is which methods are acceptable, and, why do you not wish to include your own source file?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need some basic icons, you can go for unicodes. But you will be restricted to the available codes.

Here a classical "Open Settings" button:

```
Button {
    text: "\u2630"
}
```